# Extract text with DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom

I am just beginning to learn DOM Parser.

Let's assume that in http://test.com I have **4 lines** like the one below and I am trying to extract the context as text. 
All I need is LPPR 051600Z 35010KT CAVOK 27/14 Q1020 to send as a JSON payload to an incoming webhook.

```
<FONT FACE="Monospace,Courier">LPPR 051600Z 35010KT CAVOK 27/14 Q1020</FONT><BR>
```

From this example, how can I do it using $html = str_get_html and $html->find ???

I managed to send the complete HTML content, but that's not what I want.

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://test.com')->plaintext;


// The data to send to the API

$postData = array('text' => $html);


// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://uri.com/test');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
echo $responseData['published'];
?>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that the line is exactly like this one, you can

```
$line = explode('<br>', $response);
```

This will create an array with the `<FONT>xxxxx</FONT>` of each line in each position.

To get only the text from the 2nd line

```
$filteredResponse = strip_tags($line[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PHP:DOM` is an alternative for `simple_html_dom`

below example gets links from google search.

```
<?php
# Use the Curl extension to query Google and get back a page of results
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML from Google.
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('font') as $link) {
        # Show the <font>
        echo $link->textContent;
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

`$dom->getElementsByTagName('font')` replace tag that you want.

Happy scraping

reference :
http://htmlparsing.com/php.html
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Many thanks! If I replace with the tag 'font' how will be the line echo $link->getAttribute('href');

Comment: `$link->innertext`

Comment: I just changed the iteration cycle to this one: # Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('font') as $link) {
        # Show the content
        echo $link->textContent;
        echo "<br />";
}

Comment: great let me change it in my answer